# Unit Testing Quarkus with quarkus-smallrye-openapi causing InvalidDefinitionException Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDate` not supported

Tags: jackson, quarkus

I'am using quarkus-smallrye-openapi in a quarkus 1.13.0.Final application. Everything works fine when I execute the program with `mvnw compile quarkus:dev`. However, when I execute the unit tests having some variable of LocalDate data type by running `mvn test` the program then fails to marshal and unmarshal LocalDate type objects from json and it produces

```
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
Java 8 date/time type java.time.LocalDate not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling"
```

when I remove the quarkus-smallrye-openapi dependency and relevant annotations, then the test run fine.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like a bug. Please open an issue on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

**UPDATE**:

The issue opened was: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16343
It turned out that `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb` was being used instead of `quarkus-resteasy-jackson`

Comment: as per https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16343#issuecomment-815630800 you need to use `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` instead (didn't solve the issue on my end, though)